# Bounding the norm of Gaussian random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, random-matrices

Suppose $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ is a random matrix with $n < m$, and each entry $A_{ij}$ follows i.i.d. Gaussian distribution $N(0,1/n)$. I want to know whether we can upper bound the spectral norm $\|A\|$ and $\|A^+\|$ with high probability ($A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$).

It would also be good to upper bound the expectations $E[\|A\|^p]$ for positive integer $p$. But I believe the expectations could be easily bounded once we have "with high probability" bounds.

Comment: Do you assume that your parameters $n,m$ are very large or go to $\infty$?

Comment: I think you can assume m to be sufficiently large, but not infinity (i.e. not looking for the limit of $\|A^+\|$). You can also assume that $n<<m$ under the random projection setting.

Comment: Then, given that the spectral norm of $A$ is related to the largest eigenvalue of $A^{\top}A$, which is the *sample covariance* matrix of the random vectors making up the matrix $A$, I suggest you look up results concerning the limiting behaviour of the maximal eigenvalues of sample covariance matrices. See for instance theorems 5.8 to 5.11 of http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MV_Probability/Bai%20Z.,%20Silverstein%20J.%20Spectral%20analysis%20of%20large%20dimensional%20random%20matrices%20(2ed.,%20Springer,%202010)(ISBN%201441906606)(560s)_MV_.pdf ...

Comment: ... (Spectral Theory of Large Dimensional Random Matrices by Silverstein and Bai)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer. For bounding $\|A\|^p$ one can use the rectangular matrix Bernstein inequality. For bounding $\|A^+\|$ here is a wonderful paper that provides upper bounds for all eigenvalues of a sum of random matrices: [GT11] Alex Gittens and Joel Tropp. Tail bounds for all eigenvalues of a sum of random matrices. arXiv:1104.4513, 2011. Basically you need $O(r\log r)$ more instances to bound the $r$-th eigenvalue.

Comment: Hi -- I was wondering if you could tell about how the inequality would change if the entries of the matrix had a variance $\sigma$ (i.e., \frac{1}{n} in you case here)? I know that for the std gaussian (i.e., variance is 1), the following inequality is there
$$ \mathbb{E} [\| A \| ] \leq \sqrt{ 2 \max (n, m) \log (n + m)  } $$
Pls let me know. thanks!