# Bounding the largest singular value of a random matrix with entries taken i.i.d from $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, random-matrices

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $X$ whose entries are i.i.d from a Gaussian distribution $N(0,\sigma^2) $ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$, I want to find a bound on the spectral norm of $X$, i.e. the largest singular value of $X$, in terms of $\sigma,m,n$ with high probability.

I found [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840342/bounding-the-norm-of-gaussian-random-matrix) which talks about this case with $\sigma^2 = 1/n$, but I'm looking for a more general case. They also mention one can show the bound via Bernstein Inequality, but I'm not sure how that would work, if it does also work for this case. Any explanation of this would also be great.

I don't require a full proof. I mainly am curious about an answer and any direct source I can look at that specifically mentions this problem.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm looking for a result similar to Theorem 2.6 in [these notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Erudelson/papers/rv-ICM2010.pdf) or Theorem 5.32 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf) which deal with the same question but for the the largest singular value of random matrix with entries in the standard Gaussian $N(0,1)$, bounded by $\sqrt{m} + \sqrt{n}$. I don't know if these references help but I thought I'd add them in for the kind of result I need.

Comment: It is more usual to write the variance as $\sigma^2$ so $\sigma$ would be the standard deviation

Comment: Sure. I'm not very well versed with usual notation in probability theory. It has been edited. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you basically have your answer. If the matrix $\tilde X$ has iid entries $\mathcal N\left(0,1\right)$ and its largest singular value is $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$, then your matrix $X = \sigma \tilde X$, has largest singular value $\sigma\left(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}\right)$.

Comment: It's worth noting that we also know the full distribution of singular values (look up Marcenko-Pastur distribution), but all of this, including the bound above, holds in the limit of large $m$ and $n$ (with some fixed ratio btw them). Not sure how well it holds for small $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks! I also found out about the Tracey-Widom distribution, which also can be used to get the required result with arbitrary precision.